# How to dilate a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy array of points with shape `(1000,3)` 
where axis 1 takes on values `[x,y,1]`

The points are at discrete values on a grid so an example array looks like:

```
array=([1,2,1],[4,5,1],[2,3,1],...,[xN,yN,1])
```

I would like to dilate this 2d array, and by this I mean, for each `[x,y,1]` coordinate in the array, if `[x±1,y±1,1]` is not in the array append it to the array.

currently I'm doing this with the following code:

```
np.append(array, [array[:,0],array[:,1]+1,1])
np.append(array, [array[:,0]+1,array[:,1],1])
np.append(array, [array[:,0]+1,array[:,1]+1,1])
np.append(array, [array[:,0]-1,array[:,1],1])
np.append(array, [array[:,0],array[:,1]-1,1])
np.append(array, [array[:,0]-1,array[:,1]-1,1])
np.append(array, [array[:,0]+1,array[:,1]-1,1])
np.append(array, [array[:,0]-1,array[:,1]+1,1])
```

then I am using `np.unique(array)` to reduce down to unqiue elements. This method works, but it is too slow to run on large arrays with more than 100000 points, and it doesn't feel like a smooth solution. There must be a way to do this without duplicating so many points then having to find all unique instances. Is there a different (read:faster) way to do what I am doing?

Comment: is this to be done recursively or just once?

Comment: Just a single time. If it were done recursively it would fill the whole space with 1's, no?

Comment: Given [x, y, 1], if any of [x+- 1, y+-1, 1] is not included, add it?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: Are the resulting elements unique?

Comment: Yes the elements in the base array are unique

Comment: You want to do a morphological dilation with a 3x3 square kernel on (homogeneous) pixel coordinates. Are you using OpenCV or scikit-image? Both have morphological operations that you could easily do this with---the only difference being you'd do it on the *image*, not the coordinates, but you could still just do that and use `np.where()` to get the coordinates. Or of course you could write your own function to dilate. But this seems like an easier operation to do on an image/2d array than the list of coordinates (just requires a single pass through the image). Any reason not to?

Comment: I understand the image processing applications of dilation, the issue is that I'm dealing with a point cloud and not an image. There are no 0's to fill values where there are not 1's. It would be computationally intractable to turn the large arrays I am dealing with into an image grid.

Comment: The first line of my comment was mostly for others to see, I figured you knew what you were doing :). But sounds good re: size of the arrays. Just curious, what do you need such a large array of homogeneous coordinates for? Just a transformation of a big set of point cloud? You could do connected components on the points *first* to segment into groups, and then just expand the groups by one pixel. If you don't want to add elements that already exist and then filter like you're doing, you need to do something like connected components first.

Comment: Yeah I want to target track objects as this pointcloud evolves using connected components analysis, and the first big challenge to this is creating a dilation mask that operates on pointclouds instead of an image

Comment: Typically dilation is expressed in terms of intersections with a shifted version of the image, which is exactly what you're doing. One thing to think about here is that `np.append()` is a very slow function, because it needs to create new arrays each time and you're creating larger and larger arrays each time. Small changes that could at least speed up your current implementation: find the union between each append step, so that you're appending slightly smaller arrays, and maybe strip the homogeneous 1 row beforehand.

Comment: Oh also your current implementation has an issue. You're appending to the array each time, so the next line, you're appending shifted pixels to the pixels you *already* appended. IOW if you had a single coordinate (x, y), then the first line will add (x, y+1), so now the next line is operating on two pixels instead of just the original array.

Comment: Ah sorry. I dont have the code infront of me. It's actually not doing that. I'm assigning each step to a new variable then concatenating at the end.

Comment: Just how large are your grids?

Comment: 2000*4000 in a simple 2d case. Once I move to 3d more like 2000*4000*200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2000 x 4000 x 200` is just doable with a lookup table. At just below a million coordinates I get a speedup by a factor of ~5 compared to the `np.unique` approach.

```
lookup table:  2.18715, np.unique: 11.40247
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from time import time

coords = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, 2000*4000*200, (1000000,)))
coords = np.c_[coords // (4000*200), (coords // 200) % 4000, coords % 200]

t = [time()]

ws = np.empty((2002, 4002, 202), dtype=np.uint8)
ws = as_strided(ws, (2000, 4000, 200, 3, 3, 3), 2 * ws.strides)

ws[tuple(coords.T)] = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
unq = ws[tuple(coords.T)] == np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
result = (coords[:, None, None, None, :] + np.moveaxis(np.indices((3, 3, 3)) - 1, 0, -1))[unq]
del ws

t.append(time())

result2 = np.unique((coords[:, None, None, None, :] + np.moveaxis(np.indices((3, 3, 3)) - 1, 0, -1)).reshape(-1, 3), axis = 0)

t.append(time())

print('lookup table: {:8.5f}, np.unique: {:8.5f}'.format(*np.diff(t)))
```

Comment: This worked much faster than my code. Is the second line coords=... turning a point cloud into an image?

Comment: @IanCampbellMoore It's just translating random numbers from `range(2000*4000*200)` to grid coordinates, so it is actually creating the point cloud.